# VisualStudios throws exception while codeblocks does not [C++]

Tags: c++, string, exception

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does this work in codeblocks, but in visual studios throws an exception?
2. Can someone tell me what exactly this is doing: "if (text[i + j] == word[j]) {"
   I spent hours trying to understand what it's trying to do but failed.
   Source: https://github.com/Codecademy/learn-cpp/tree/master/8-references-and-pointers/bleep

Do I still need to point out I'm new to programming? Well I'm new so take it slow.

btw before looking at their solution I did find a way to do it using google I found the replace() function worked for me. But I still copied and pasted = no good. Their's is more natural without the use of others/inbuilt function(s).

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "functions.h"

int main() {
  
  std::string word = "broccoli";
  
  std::string sentence = "I sometimes eat broccoli. The interesting thing about broccoli is that there are four interesting things about broccoli. Number One. Nobody knows how to spell it. Number Two. No matter how long you boil it, it's always cold by the time it reaches your plate. Number Three. It's green. #broccoli";
  
  bleep(word, sentence);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
    
    std::cout << sentence[i];
    
  }
  
  std::cout << "\n";
  
}
```

functions.h

```
  
void bleep(std::string word, std::string &text);
void asterisk(std::string word, std::string &text, int i);
```

functions.cpp

```
#include <string>

void asterisk(std::string word, std::string &text, int i) {
  
  for (int k = 0; k < word.size(); ++k) {
  
    text[i+k] = '*';
      
  }
  
}

void bleep(std::string word, std::string &text) {
    
  for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
        
    int match = 0;
        
    for (int j = 0; j < word.size(); ++j) {
    
      if (text[i+j] == word[j]) {
        
        ++match;
          
      }
    
    }
        
    if (match == word.size()) {
            
      asterisk(word, text, i);
        
    }
      
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
if (text[i+j] == word[j])
```

you are indexing too far into `text`. If you index out of bounds, that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Anything can happen, including working on one platform, but not on another.

Since you only want to find complete words, you can make the index `i` stop earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.size() - word.size(); ++i)
```

Comment: But why does it work perfectly in codeblocks without a hickup? Like it's serves a different purpose? Or is exception ignored? Does ignoring exception will work? and my question is what is it saying to the machine if it works in codeblocks? None technical explanationif possible. it it comparing the strings whole word at the index # to blank to see if it matches? that's what i'm trying to understand.

Comment: Like I said, it's undefined behavior, so anything can happen. It only appears to work in codeblocks, it's still broken.

Comment: @UniverseX *None technical explanationif possible* -- Ok.  Your driver's license is taken away from you.  Does that stop you from getting into a car and driving it?  No, it doesn't.  Now you are driving this car, and you drive for miles and no policeman is around to stop you.  Does that make getting into the car and driving it legal?  No.  Now your friend who has his license taken away from him does the same thing as you, and he gets stopped by the police after driving a few yards.  You both did something illegal, but your friend got stopped, but you didn't.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: "why does it work in code blocks"? -- bad luck.